# Curvature of a circle using tensors

Tags: tensors, curvature

Using the tensor methods in polar coordinates, find the curvature of the circle:

$x^1=b$

$x^2=t$

with $t$ a free parameter and $b$ a constant.

I know how to obtain the curvature of any parametric curve in the usual way (using real variable calculus) but I don't understand how it is obtained using tensors. I appreciate your time and help.

Comment: May be you should induce the definition of the curvature in the general tensor notation. If you don't have it, at least state the definition of curvature that you are using.

Comment: I am working with $k(s) =\sqrt{\delta_{ij} \cfrac{d^2x^i} {ds^2}\cfrac{d^2x^j} {ds^2} }$

Comment: Your equality is true only when your curve has constant length parametrization. You need to find the general formula, or an intrinsic definition of the curvature.